# How to install Feedparser 5.1 for Python 3.2 Windows 64 bit.

Tags: python, installation, feedparser, windows64

I'm trying to install [Feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) 5.1 for Python 3.2, Windows 64 bit.

I have tried FOREVER (aka the past 2 weeks) to install Feedparser for Python, and have been failing miserably. I've read the readme, tried searching the internet, and nothing has worked for me.  Needless to say, I feel completely stupid.

Will someone PLEASE give me step-by-step instructions to install Feedparser 5.1 for Python 3.2 Windows 64 bit. I'm desperate, please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Approach A: Using Pip

The best method for installing FeedParser (or almost any Python package) is by using `pip`, Python's package manager. `pip` will be installed by default alongside Python as of Python 3.4 (and Python 2.7.9). Since the latest version of Python (as of time of editing) is Python 3.5, this is really the approach you should be taking whenever possible.

To run pip, do the following:

1. Open the command line.  You can do this by clicking start, then typing `cmd` in the `run` textbox.
2. Make sure you are connected to the internet.
3. Type in `pip install feedparser` and hit enter (and wait for pip to download and install FeedParser)

You're done! Open up IDLE and type in `import feedparser` to confirm.

If attempting to use `pip` fails for some reason, try...

1. Typing in `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install feedparser` (or wherever you installed Python)
2. Closing the command line, and re-opening it in admin mode (click start, type 'cmd', right-click, select "Run as Administrator"), if it's failing due to permission errors

If you would like to learn more about pip, or need help setting it up on older versions of Python, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731459/646543).

## Approach B: Manual install

If, for some reason, you are unable to use `pip`, you can always try doing a manual install.

### Part A: Prerequisites:

Feedburner needs a module named `setuptools` in order to install.  Unfortunately, `setuptools` isn't compatible with Python 3.x, but you can use something called `Distribute` as a convenient replacement.  If you already have this installed, you can skip Part A.

1. Download the "installer" here: http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py. This is a Python script that will download the required components from the internet and install `Distribute` for you.
2. Open the command line.  You can do this by clicking start, then typing `cmd` in the `run` textbox.  Navigate over to the folder containing `distribute_setup.py` by using `cd`.  On my system, I typed `cd C:\Users\Michael0x2a\Downloads`
3. Type `python distribute_setup.py` (and if that doesn't work, `C:\Python32\python.exe distribute_setup.py` (or wherever you did install Python)).  A bunch of text should appear and scroll by.

### Part B: Actually installing feedparser:

1. Download and extract the latest file from here: https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/releases
2. Navigate in the command line to where the extracted feedparser folder is by using the `cd` command.  For example, on my computer, I typed:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\Michael0x2a\Downloads\feedparser-5.1\feedparser-5.1
   ```

   (Your version number will probably differ. For example, you might have `feedparser-5.3` or something)
3. Make sure the folder you're in has the readme, various other docs, and `setup.py`.  To check, type `dir` into the command line.  It should list the files and folders there.
4. Type `python setup.py install` (or `C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py install`.).  Text should appear and slowly scroll by.

You're done!  Open up IDLE and type `import feedparser` to confirm.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  You gave me exactly what I needed!!!!!!!!!!!!! I found examples similar but they all skipped steps and I became so confused you are the best Thank You So Much!

Comment: Glad to help :).  If the answer worked for you, press the check mark to the left of my answer to accept it, and maybe even upvote my answer.

Comment: The internet domain "python-distribute.org" exists no more. The relative link :"http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py" does not works.