# Python: How to force overwriting of files when using setup.py install (distutil)

Tags: python, installation, distutils, overwrite

I am using `distutil` to install my python code using

`python setup.py install`

I run into problems when I want to install an older branch of my code over a new one:
`setup.py install` won't overwrite older files. A work around is touching (`touch <filename>`) all files so they are forced to be newer than those installed, but this is pretty ugly.

What I am looking for is an option to force overwriting of all files, eg. something like

`python setup.py --force install`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The Python developers had the same idea, they just put the option after the command:

```
python setup.py install --force
```

The distutils documentation doesn't mention the `--force` option specifically, but you can find it by using the `--help` option:

```
python setup.py --help install
```

Comment: Note, the --force overwrites, and does not remove files.  I find I depend on pip uninstall <package> when I need to switch versions. Otherwise, you do not know what is lurking. If pip is not an option, then I think you have to manually remove /bin/<package-programs> and /lib/python/site-packages/<package>. Again, pip is your friend.

Comment: The `--force` option does not appear to be documented nor functional in python3.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the `setup.py` directory and I simply use:

```
pip install .
```

It works for me.

Comment: It also works for me. It properly overwrites my files, even `install --force` didn't do that for some reason. setup.py seems to be properly executed and all my files are copied to where they should go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731459/4417769 "So basically, use pip. It only offers improvements"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to remove the build and dist folders

```
rm -rf build
rm -rf dist
python3 setup.py install
```