# Why does pip install a different package version within travis?

Tags: python, pip, travis-ci

In a package I'm maintaining, I have a `requirements.txt` containing an unpinned dependency `pandas`. Installing my package shows different behavior locally vs on Travis:

- Running `pip install` on the package locally leads to installing Pandas version `0.24.2`.
- Running the same `pip install` within Travis CI leads to installing Pandas version `0.25.0rc0` ([link to job](https://travis-ci.org/bluenote10/tabloo/jobs/558520521)).

In both cases the cases the versions of pip and setuptools are the same (`pip==19.1.1`, `setuptools==41.0.1`).

I'm not specifying an explicit index (and locally I don't have a global pip config), so I'm assuming both should use the standard PyPI index. Looking into [the available versions on PyPi](https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) I can see that both `0.24.2` and `0.25.0rc0` are available.

How is it possible that I'm getting a different version locally compared to Travis? Does Travis have some kind of global pip config that would e.g. allow RC versions to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, an error in my Travis config happened to execute `python setup.py install` where I was expecting to see the output of `pip install -e .`.

Apparently, `python setup.py install` has a different logic to interpret unpinned dependencies in a `requirements.txt` and picks the RC version (see [Q/A difference between `python setup.py` and `pip install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724093/difference-between-python-setup-py-install-and-pip-install) for general differences). I thought I can support both `python setup.py install` and `pip install`, but given the discrepancies in dependency resolution it's probably best to support `pip` only.