# Automating post-install of Python dependency from Git using Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm using [Poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry) for Python dependency management, along with [PyCrate](https://github.com/P1sec/pycrate) for ASN.1 encoding/decoding.

PyCrate is a dependency pulled from GitHub, and once pulled from GitHub, is installed by running a setup file within the PyCrate directory.

```
python setup.py install
```

I would like to integrate the installation step into my `pyproject.toml`, if possible. My current `pyproject.toml` includes PyCrate as follows:

```
…
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pycrate = {git = "https://github.com/P1sec/pycrate.git"}
…
```

This will pull PyCrate from the GitHub repository, but into the `src` folder in the virtualenv created by Poetry.

Is there any way to automatically run the setup script when performing a `poetry install`? I have looked into using [Poetry scripts](https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/pyproject/#scripts), but haven't been able to get this up and running correctly as of yet.

My current setup involves running a `poetry install`, then manually running the `setup.py install` for PyCrate, however I would like to have my `poetry install` to perform the full setup, if it can be done.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poetry should already run `python setup.py install` for you when you run `poetry install`.

Poetry basically just runs `pip install package`, which downloads the package, and essentially just runs `python setup.py install` on the package!

> Under the hood, [pip] will run `python setup.py install`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732821/10149169

However, **poetry only installs the package inside an isolated virtual environment**, to avoid polluting the rest of your computer.

## To run something with poetry, you need to run it with `poetry run YOUR_COMMAND`

In order to run a script inside the virtual environment, you must run `poetry shell` to enter the virtual environment, or `poetry run YOUR_COMMAND`. E.g. to run a Python script, you should do `poetry run python your_python_script.py`

### Example

If you have a folder with the following `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
pycrate = {git = "https://github.com/P1sec/pycrate.git"}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

After running `poetry install`, you can access all the pyrcrate scripts by running `poetry run SCRIPT_NAME`:

```
# works because pycrate_showmedia.py was installed with poetry install
me@computer:~/example-project$ poetry run poetry run pycrate_showmedia.py
usage: pycrate_showmedia.py [-h] [-bl BL] [-wt] input
pycrate_showmedia.py: error: the following arguments are required: input
```

If you have a Python file that imports a pycrate library, it also needs to be run using `poetry run`:

```
me@computer:~/example-project$ cat test.py 
import pycrate_core
print(pycrate_core.__version__)
me@computer:~/example-project$ poetry run python test.py
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: I'm confused, this does **not** appear to be automated. If I send this package to someone else, they would also have to run `poetry run post-install.py`

Comment: Hi @IsaiahShiner, the author was asking about automatically installing dependencies using poetry, which assumes all the dependencies can be installed via `pip`, e.g. by running `python setup.py install`. Python packages usually don't have a `post-install.py` script, since anything in it can just be added to the end of the `setup.py` file.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what the author was asking. I suppose my question is different: how do I add to setup.py with poetry, since there is no setup.py. I can't find any information on this.

Comment: @AloisKlink I created my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802468/post-install-script-with-python-poetry