# Post-install script with Python Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

[Post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools)

Exactly this question, but with Poetry and no Setuptools.

I want to run

```
print('Installation finished, doing other things...')
```

when my package is installed. With Setuptools you could just modify `setup.py`, but in Poetry there specifically is no `setup.py`.

What I actually want to do is generate a default `.mypackage_config` file and place it somewhere useful. I don't see how to do this without arbitrary code, but Poetry [does not allow arbitrary code](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/265) for installation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: maybe this? https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts

Comment: The 'scripts' section of Poetry is a kinda misleading. It's Poetry's version of setuptools 'entry_points', which let's you create command line entrances to your package. It won't run the scripts automatically and isn't meant for that. https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## It's not currently possible (and probably won't ever be)

The entire idea of poetry is that a package can be installed without running any arbitrary Python code. Because of that, custom post-install scripts will probably never exist ([from the author of poetry, the link you gave in your question](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/265)).

## What you could do instead

You could use setuptools, and modify the `setup.py` script, but it's probably easier to remove the need for a post-install script by removing the need for a default config file.

Most Python tools, such as [black](https://github.com/psf/black/), tend to assume default config parameters, unless there are settings in a config file (such as a `pyproject.toml` file) that overrides them, e.g.:

```
[tool.black] # specifies this next section is the config for black
line-length = 88 # changes some configuration parameters from the defaults
target-version = ['py36', 'py37']
```

Jupyter has a command `jupyterhub --generate-config` to generate a default config file ([source](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/config-basics.html#generate-a-default-config-file)).

If your package is a library, not a command-line tool, i.e. you use it by `import`-ing it in your Python code, I'd recommend just passing in the configuration as arguments to the constructor/functions, since that's the standard way of passing config to a library.

As an example, look at [PySerial's API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports). You can configure the library by passing args to the constructor `serial.Serial`, e.g.:

```py
import serial
with serial.Serial(
    '/dev/ttyUSB0', # first config param, the port
    19200, # second config param, the baudrate
    timeout=5, # sets the timeout config param
) as ser:
```

Comment: Somehow, it didn't occur to me to use default values unless otherwise overridden. A `--generate-config` command also makes a ton of sense. Some very good ideas. There really is no need to run arbitrary code at install time.

Comment: No worries! To be honest, the only reason it occurred to me is because I've seen how quite a few different Python packages (and some Linux programs) do it, and I just copied what I thought they did well in my answer. Good luck with developing your package!

Answer (score 2):

at my current project we decided to create a bootstrap script, maybe it's the best way to go