# How to deal with setup.py overwriting sub-package dependencies

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

The problem I am facing is that setuptools overwrite the sub-package dependency requirements.

Example:

setup.py

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="test",
    version="0.1",
    author="myself",
    author_email="info@example.com",
    description="How to manage dependencies?",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha"
    ],
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'dependency-injector',
    ]
)
```

Installation successful via `python setup.py install`

Output:

```
(venv) alex@ws:~$ pip freeze
dependency-injector==3.14.12
six==1.12.0
test==0.1
```

If you use the following setup.py **including six as dependency** (because you need it in your package), then you hit problems, because dependency-injector also needs the dependency though they have defined a fixed version range.

```
import os
from setuptools import setup



setup(
    name="test",
    version="0.1",
    author="myself",
    author_email="info@example.com",
    description="How to manage dependencies?",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha"
    ],
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'dependency-injector',
        'six'
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
error: six 1.13.0 is installed but six<=1.12.0,>=1.7.0 is required by {'dependency-injector'}
(venv) alex@ws:~$ pip freeze
dependency-injector==3.14.12
six==1.13.0
test==0.1
```

For sure a working solution is just to repeat the same six version range which dependency-injector uses (see the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector/blob/master/requirements.txt) file in their repo), though I would really like to avoid this duplicate definition of dependencies, because e.g. dependency-injector might upgrade the six version dependency and thus I need to also update my package. So I will always try to mimic their requirements which is bad practice.

I think actually the only clean solution would be that setuptools builds up a dependency tree and and then uses the versions matching the requirements of all dependencies.
Is this realistic? How can it be achieved or what is the recommended best-practice in such a case as described above?

Comment: Which command wrote this error message?

Comment: `python setup.py install`. I just added it to the question. Good question. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it. I thought somehow I would find related bugs on the _setuptools_ issue tracker, but couldn't find any. I would suggest using `pip install .` instead of `python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Appreciate it. Indeed, `pip install .` solves the problem. I just verified. Funny. Because yesterday I also tried a requirements.txt file with both requirements and then a `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it fails due to the exact same reason.
I know too little though about setuptools and pip to judge now if it is the same root cause and why `pip install .` works though. I would really like to at least report this bug so that it gets fixed at some point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TL;DR answer is that **`pip` currently does not have a dependency solver**.

There is an ongoing issue on `pip`'s issue tracker on just that topic: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988
What they say is that currently `pip`'s behavior is "first found wins", so your top-level `six` dependency is resolved before `dependency-injector`'s `six` dependency, which is why you get the latest `six` version installed in the end.

On the `python setup.py install` vs. `pip install .` question, there seems to be a subtle difference between the two commands. They don't use the same tools internally, and the recommended command is `pip install .` generally

(sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731459/9977650, https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/960)

Comment: True, I agree an almost everything except the premise... If I am not mistaken the original question doesn't use _pip install_ to begin with but only _setuptools_' `python setup.py install`. And actually using `pip install` seems to solve the issue, so _pip_'s dependency resolution seems to be good enough at least in this case.