# Difference between installation of pip git+https and python setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724093/difference-between-python-setup-py-install-and-pip-install) popular topic, however I am running into a different outcome when installing a `python` app using `pip` with `git+https` and `python` `setup.py`

I am building a `docker` image. I am trying to install in an image containing several other python apps, [this](https://github.com/alerta/alerta-contrib/tree/master/webhooks/sentry) custom webhook.

1. Using `git+https`

```
RUN /venv/bin/pip install git+https://github.com/alerta/alerta-contrib.git#subdirectory=webhooks/sentry
```

This seems to install the webhook the right way, as the relevant endpoint is l8r discoverable.
What is more, when I exec into the running container and doing a search for relevant files, I see the following

```
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/__pycache__/alerta_sentry.cpython-37.pyc
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk-0.15.1.dist-info
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta_sentry.py
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta_sentry-5.0.0-py3.7.egg-info
```

2. In my second approach I just copy this directory locally and in my `Dockerfile` I do

```
COPY sentry /app/sentry
RUN /venv/bin/python /app/sentry/setup.py install
```

This does not install the webhook appropriately and what is more, in the respective container I see a different file layout

```
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk-0.15.1.dist-info
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta_sentry-5.0.0-py3.7.egg
./alerta_sentry.egg-info
./dist/alerta_sentry-5.0.0-py3.7.egg
```

(the `sentry_sdk` - related files must be irrelevant)

Why does the second approach fail to install the webhook appropriately?

Should these two option yield the same result?

Comment: "*Should these two option yield the same result?*" No, why? The 1st link in your question explains the difference and even after reading the answers there you still expect them to be equivalent? Why?

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked is the following

```
RUN /venv/bin/pip install /app/sentry/
```

I don't know the subtle differences between these two installation modes

I did notice however that `/venv/bin/python /app/sentry/setup.py install` did not produce an `alerta_sentry.py` but only the `.egg` file, i.e. `./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta_sentry-5.0.0-py3.7.egg`

On the other hand, `/venv/bin/pip install /app/sentry/` unpacked (?) the `.egg` creating the `./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta_sentry.py`

I don't also know why the second installation option (i.e. the one creating the `.egg` file) was not working run time.