# Is it possible to use pipenv with setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, pipenv, pyenv

As the title states -- can I use setup.py with pipenv with pyenv to manage my environments, versions, and dependencies?

I have a python package in the form of a directory structure with a setup.py file.

I love using pipenv as my project environment manager -- I use pyenv for managing my multiple python version.

So what I'm trying to do is:

1. Use pyenv to get a project specifc python version: `pyenv version 3.8.5`
2. run the setupfile using python setup.py install -- say this package is called foobar -- this installs the package in ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/foobar (the real name is not foobar -- just using that here to illustrate the point)
3. Now when I go to my_project and run pipenv install foobar -- I get the following:

```
pipenv install foobar
Installing foobar…
Error:  An error occurred while installing foobar!
Error text:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement foobar (from -r /var/folders/2d/f68m9g153v9cywvjn16hs6nc0000gn/T/pipenv-4uv_ikyt-requirements/pipenv-asuqkc7y-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for foobar (from -r /var/folders/2d/f68m9g153v9cywvjn16hs6nc0000gn/T/pipenv-4uv_ikyt-requirements/pipenv-asuqkc7y-requirement.txt (line 1))

✘ Installation Failed
```

At a loss.

Answer (score 9):

I don't use pyenv but the principle is the same: you have a locally installable package (using setup.py), and Pipenv does support those with its `install` command, and it calls them [editable dependencies](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#editable-dependencies-e-g-e).

> You can tell Pipenv to install a path as editable — often this is useful for the current working directory when working on packages:
>
> ```
> $ pipenv install --dev -e .  
>   
> $ cat Pipfile  
> ...  
> [dev-packages]  
> "e1839a8" = {path = ".", editable = true}
> ...
> ```

Let's take your `foobar` from a `libraries` folder:

```
libraries$ tree
.
├── foobar
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

To install that to some other virtual environment with `pipenv`:

```
myapp$ pipenv install -e /path/to/libraries
...
Installing -e /path/to/libraries...
Adding foobar to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded
```

```
myapp$ cat Pipfile
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
foobar = {editable = true, path = "/path/to/libraries"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

```
myapp$ pipenv shell
(myapp) myapp$ python
>>> import foobar
>>> foobar.add(1,2)
3
```

Notice that you don't need the step of installing your package with [`python setup.py install` or `pip install .`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15724093/2745495). The nice thing here is if you now edit `foobar` codes, it gets reflected in that other environment without needing for repeated `pipenv install`.

Installing it to *lib/python3.8/site-packages* (or wherever `pyenv` installs packages) by running

```
python setup.py install
```

will not work, because that's not the correct flow. You prepare your `foobar` for distribution, and then install it *from a distribution*, not from *site-packages*, which is already the installed version (does not have setup.py). You could probably work it around by copying the entire `foobar` package to your `pyenv`'s *site-packages* folder (including setup.py), then tell `pipenv` to install it from there.... but that's just not the correct flow.

An alternative to `pipenv install -e`, if you want to test your actual source distribution, is to actually build your source distribution of `foobar`, then `pipenv install` from that.

```
libraries$ python3.8 setup.py sdist
...
Creating tar archive
...

libraries$ tree
.
...
├── dist
│   ├── foobar-0.1.0-py3.8.egg
│   └── foobar-0.1.0.tar.gz
├── foobar
│   └── __init__.py
├── ...
└── setup.py
```

```
(myapp) myapp$ pipenv install /path/to/libraries/dist/foobar-0.1.0.tar.gz
Installing /path/to/libraries/dist/foobar-0.1.0.tar.gz...
```

```
(myapp) myapp$ cat Pipfile
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
foobar = {path = "/path/to/libraries/dist/foobar-0.1.0.tar.gz"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

But installing from `sdist` loses the convenience of quickly seeing the updates to `foobar` when you use it on your other apps. I don't know what your workflow is, but I prefer having a common directory (`libraries`) instead where I store all locally-editable packages, then `pipenv install`-ing from there.