# A question about pip install vs python setup.py install

Tags: python, github

What is the main difference in installing a python package by `pip install` and `python setup.py install` using the file from GitHub repository?

From what I understand right now, I kinda have the feeling that using the second option you will install the repo in some sort of *developer* mode where you can do changes by directly operating in the files cloned by git repo. Is this correct? I would like to find out a proper explanation of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'python setup.py install' and 'pip install'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724093/difference-between-python-setup-py-install-and-pip-install)

Comment: The difference is that question mentions an archive, and this question is about the git/source directory. But I think the archive and git/source directory is interchangeable via a tar operation, so it's pretty similar.