# What is the difference between "pip install ." and "python setup.py install"?

Tags: python, pip

I always thought you can install a python package by

1. Checking out the code (e.g. `git clone ...`)
2. cd into that folder
3. Run `pip install .`

But now I read that you need to run

```
python setup.py install
```

to install all dependencies defined in `install_requires` in `setup.py` (see [HERE](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-package-python-dependencies-with-pip-setuptools/)).

Can someone please explain the differences? And why `pip install` ignores the package list in `install_requires`? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: It would be similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731459/11922177

Comment: Wow, but this answer tells me the opposite of how things are. `pip install` seems to ignore `install_requires` while `setup.py` does not. 

The answer given in the other place confuses me even more. The answer does not make any sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'python setup.py install' and 'pip install'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724093/difference-between-python-setup-py-install-and-pip-install)

Comment: thanks,you remind me that `pip install . -i index-url` could be work in internal source and seem effect equal to `python setup.py install`